# Combine continuation lines starting with "+"

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I know this is a question that was asked many times, I didn't find an answer that answers my specific question.

Essentially, I have an input file where some lines begin with a `+` string. These lines must be appended at the end of the previous line and the `+` character must be removed. So

```
abc
def
+ ghj
klm
```

should become

```
abc
def ghj
klm
```

This is the perl command I crafted by looking at other answers

```
perl -pe 's/\n\+ //m' < input
```

but it prints the input file without changing it. The odd thing is that, on websites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), my regex produces the expected result.

What am I missing?

Comment: It is because the perl one liner reads line by line from the input file

Comment: Is it an unavoidable limitation? Right now, I'm using this sed expression to solve the problem

'1h;1\!H;${;g;s/\n+ / /g;p;}'

but people advised my to not use this with large files

Comment: Ok, the -0777 option makes it work. Are there any inconveniences in the use of this option?

Comment: Yes, -0777 will slurp the whole file into memory. So, If file is huge and your memory is limited then it may cause inconveniences.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wanted an one liner because this operation will be performed in a shell script. I'll have to ask the people who will use it about their file size. I think they are up to 100k lines

Comment: @Patrik: That is tiny, and will only occupy around 1MB of memory maximum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably these are relatively small files and so will easily fit into memory?

This is the simplest way

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

$data =~ s/\n\+//g;

print $data;

__DATA__
abc
def
+ ghj
klm
```

#### output

```
abc
def ghj
klm
```

In a Perl one-liner that would be

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\+//g' < input
```

Comment: Yes, in the end this one liner is the solution I adopted

Answer (score 2):

You can change the input record separator `$/` to the string `"\n+"` *(or `"\r\n+"` for a Windows file)*, then you only need to chomp each records:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="\n+"}chomp' file
```

Comment: I assume this will keep reading lines until it finds a \n+. Then it removes it and print the chomped "row". Original \n are kept so lined that should not be joined are not joined in the print. Is this corrent? BTW, shouldn't \n+ match "one or more \n"?

Comment: @Patrik The contents of `$/` are a simple string, not a regex pattern

Comment: @Patrik: yes it is. As mentioned by Borodin `\n+` is indeed a string with two literal characters, not a regex pattern. The main advantage of this method is that the whole file isn't loaded in memory, but is read paragraph by paragraph. It can be useful for large files. *(except for giant paragraphs, but you can have the same problem reading a file line by line)*

Answer (score 1):

@Borodin has provided a good solution for your question. Besides, if you need to update that into the old file , just add "-i":

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\n\+//g' input
```

or if you want to keep an source file as backup ,use:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's/\n\+//g' input
```

this will generate a file named input.bak in case you want to recovery.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I knew about the -i option, as with sed

Comment: This is the most correct answer because inline replace is more efficient because it only loads what it needs